# Bounding the standard deviation of a bounded random variable

Tags: probability, statistics, standard-deviation

Suppose $X$ is a random variable (discrete or continuous) whose values lie in the segment $[0,1]$. Is it safe to say that the standard deviation of $X$ is between $0$ and $\frac{1}{2}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes.  $(X-1/2)^2 \le 1/4$, so 
$$ \text{Var}(X) = \text{Var}(X-1/2) = E[(X-1/2)^2] - (E[X]-1/2)^2 \le 1/4$$

Comment: Thanks, that's a great and simple solution.